# strpbrk doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c, string, function, design-patterns, output

first I want to say, I'm pretty new to C.
I have a problem with the strpbrk function.

My function gets a string.
If this string contains a "¼", it should do something, if it contains a "¾" it should do something else.

```
static char* format_date_string3(char *string) {
   printf("Found: %s\n", strpbrk(string, "¼"));
   if (strpbrk(string, "¼") != NULL) {
       //do something
   } else if (strpbrk(string, "¾") != NULL) {
       //do something else
   }
}
```

I added the printf for debugging purposes.

The Problem is that the output is "Found: ¼" if the string was "¼" and "Found: ¾" if the string was "¾". But for "¾" I expected the output to be NULL since the searched pattern isn't in the string. Why is this not the case? How can I change it?

Is the reason maybe that ¼ aren't "normal" characters?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This part seems self-contradictory : `"Found: ¼" if the string was "¼" and "Found: ¾" if the string was "¾". But for "¾" I expected the output to be NULL since the searched pattern isn't in the string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`strpbrk()` does not support multibyte encodings.**

Most likely the [¼](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/be/index.htm) and [¾](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bc/index.htm) in your source code are getting encoded as UTF-8 but interpreted at runtime as ASCII.

The UTF-8 encodings for the two characters are:

```
0xC2 0xBC
0xC2 0xBE
```

Since they share a common ASCII "character", `0xC2`, `strpbrk()` is returning something other than `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean I can't use strpbrk for these characters? Is there an alternative?

Comment: @user1894572: This *might* be useful: http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html